# Define Required field in typescript class

Tags: typescript

I want to Define required field in .ts file And I try this code but it doesn't work.

```
class Person {
    required(FirstName: string);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Try to provide more information for others to help you.

Comment: I want to Define a typescript class that can validate itself, for example declare a required field and validate in client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the validation yourself if you are interested in a runtime validation. You can go with:

```
class Person {
    public firstName:string;
    constructor(firstName: string) {    
        // You can add any validation you want here.
        if (!firstName) {
             throw new Error("Invalid name!");
        } 
        this.firstName = firstName; 
    }    
}

let p = new Person(null); // throws an error
```

or

```
class Person {
    public firstName:string;
    validateData() {
        if (!this.firstName) {
             throw new Error("Invalid name!");
        } 
    } 
}

let p = new Person();
p.validateData(); // throws an error
```

PS: I recommend to study [TypeScript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook) first because it most likely answers all your questions if you start with TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
class Person {
   FirstName: string;
}

var foo:Person = {}; // Error `FirstName` is required
```

Comment: but what about `var foo=new Person();`? That will work, but foo will not have a value for FirstName